# Default magento cron.sh generating infinite number of processes

Tags: cron

I am struggling with something really strange here. When I set up the Magento cron.sh, it spawns an infinite number of "ps" processes which bring down my server.

The content of the file is the default one:

```
#!/bin/sh
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
        MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#       prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

Cron.php is also default, however for some reason cron.sh is flooding the server with the mentioned "ps" processes. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I was just up against this issue too. Our problem resided in the line:

```
PHP_BIN=`which php`
```

If you run 'cron.sh' manually while SSH'd in your server, does it run successfully? If so, it's possible that your user PATH is different than the cron PATH when it runs, causing your cron.sh using the wrong php client.

Example, in our system, PHP_BIN was set to /usr/bin/php when ran by cron, however, when we ran it manually, PHP_BIN was set to /usr/local/bin/php.

To test this, create this test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PHP_BIN=`which php`

echo $PHP_BIN >> /tmp/whichPhp.log
echo $PATH >> /tmp/whichPhp.log
```

Add your test.sh in your system cron, and also run the test.sh file manually while SSH'd in your terminal. If the "PHP_BIN" value is different, then you will need to adjust your PATH in your crontab to use the correct php client.

If both cron and manual executions, result in the same PHP_BIN value, it's possible that your php client is actually php-cgi. To determine this, run

> php -i

in your terminal. If it starts spitting out HTML, then this is not a true php-cli version, and you will need to install/configure your php client version.

What kind of access do you have to your server? If you have good support, you might be able to use the information above to enter a ticket, and have your hosting address the issue.